# BASH script: Downloading consecutive numbered files with wget

Tags: bash, scripting, wget

I have a web server that saves the logs files of a web application numbered. A file name example for this would be:

```
dbsclog01s001.log
dbsclog01s002.log
dbsclog01s003.log
```

The last 3 digits are the counter and they can get sometime up to 100.

I usually open a web browser, browse to the file like:

```
http://someaddress.com/logs/dbsclog01s001.log
```

and save the files. This of course gets a bit annoying when you get 50 logs.
I tried to come up with a BASH script for using wget and passing

```
http://someaddress.com/logs/dbsclog01s*.log
```

but I am having problems with my the script. 
Anyway, anyone has a sample on how to do this?

thanks!

Comment: `*` is local filename expansion - it only works for files in the current path for your own machine. You will have to loop through all the remote addresses.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -lt 3 ]; then
        echo "Usage: $0 url_format seq_start seq_end [wget_args]"
        exit
fi

url_format=$1
seq_start=$2
seq_end=$3
shift 3

printf "$url_format\\n" `seq $seq_start $seq_end` | wget -i- "$@"
```

Save the above as `seq_wget`, give it execution permission (`chmod +x seq_wget`), and then run, for example:

```
$ ./seq_wget http://someaddress.com/logs/dbsclog01s%03d.log 1 50
```

Or, if you have Bash 4.0, you could just type

```
$ wget http://someaddress.com/logs/dbsclog01s{001..050}.log
```

Or, if you have `curl` instead of `wget`, you could follow Dennis Williamson's answer.

Comment: bash+wget answer should be an answer by itself.  it's the simplest and quickest way to do this.

Comment: Approach "wget http://someaddress.com/logs/dbsclog01s{001..050}.log" worked for me: Ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 44):

`curl` seems to support ranges. From the `man` page:

```
URL  
       The URL syntax is protocol dependent. You’ll find a  detailed  descrip‐
       tion in RFC 3986.

       You  can  specify  multiple  URLs or parts of URLs by writing part sets
       within braces as in:

        http://site.{one,two,three}.com

       or you can get sequences of alphanumeric series by using [] as in:

        ftp://ftp.numericals.com/file[1-100].txt
        ftp://ftp.numericals.com/file[001-100].txt    (with leading zeros)
        ftp://ftp.letters.com/file[a-z].txt

       No nesting of the sequences is supported at the moment, but you can use
       several ones next to each other:

        http://any.org/archive[1996-1999]/vol[1-4]/part{a,b,c}.html

       You  can  specify  any amount of URLs on the command line. They will be
       fetched in a sequential manner in the specified order.

       Since curl 7.15.1 you can also specify step counter for the ranges,  so
       that you can get every Nth number or letter:

        http://www.numericals.com/file[1-100:10].txt
        http://www.letters.com/file[a-z:2].txt
```

You may have noticed that it says "with leading zeros"!

Comment: You can also reference the sequences 
`curl http://example.com/logs/dbsclog01s[001-100].log -o log#1.log`

Answer (score 21):

You can use echo type sequences in the wget url to download a string of numbers...

`wget http://someaddress.com/logs/dbsclog01s00{1..3}.log`

This also works with letters

`{a..z} {A..Z}`

Comment: Any idea how to specify echo type sequence via script's parameters?

Comment: Not sure if you could do it with wget, i know it works with curl `curl http://someaddress.com/logs/dbsclog01s00[1-${variable}].log`

Answer (score 14):

Not sure precisely what problems you were experiencing, but it sounds like a simple for loop in bash would do it for you.

```
for i in {1..999}; do
wget -k http://someaddress.com/logs/dbsclog01s$i.log -O your_local_output_dir_$i;
done
```

Comment: Of course, you'll want to replace '999' with the actual number of files, or maybe add some logic to count them beforehand. The input and output strings might need some refinement too, depending on how the "real" URL looks.

Comment: my problem was turning something similar to what you just wrote to a script that can accept the URL and file name as arguments.

Comment: Ah! So, you're looking for something like a little bash utility that would take the URL literal, the output file literal, and the number of files, then run the wget loop based on that info? $0, $1, $2 etc are the input arguments in bash scripts, so I could adjust the example to reflect that if you confirm this is what you're looking for.

Comment: There should only be two dots in the range "{1..999}".

Answer (score 12):

You can use a combination of [a for loop i](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/)n bash with the [printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) command (of course modifying `echo` to `wget` as needed):

```
$ for i in {1..10}; do echo "http://www.com/myurl`printf "%03d" $i`.html"; done
http://www.com/myurl001.html
http://www.com/myurl002.html
http://www.com/myurl003.html
http://www.com/myurl004.html
http://www.com/myurl005.html
http://www.com/myurl006.html
http://www.com/myurl007.html
http://www.com/myurl008.html
http://www.com/myurl009.html
http://www.com/myurl010.html
```

Comment: thanks. How can I turn thing into a full script that accept the URL as an argument?

Answer (score 3):

Interesting task, so I wrote full script for you (combined several answers and more). Here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash
# fixed vars
URL=http://domain.com/logs/     # URL address 'till logfile name
PREF=logprefix                  # logfile prefix (before number)
POSTF=.log                      # logfile suffix (after number)
DIGITS=3                        # how many digits logfile's number have
DLDIR=~/Downloads               # download directory
TOUT=5                          # timeout for quit
# code
for((i=1;i<10**$DIGITS;++i))
do
        file=$PREF`printf "%0${DIGITS}d" $i`$POSTF   # local file name
        dl=$URL$file                                 # full URL to download    
        echo "$dl -> $DLDIR/$file"                   # monitoring, can be commented
        wget -T $TOUT -q $dl -O $file
        if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]                            # test if we finished
        then
                exit
        fi
done
```

At the beggiing of the script you can set URL, log file prefix and suffix, how many digits you have in numbering part and download directory. Loop will download all logfiles it found, and automaticaly exit on first non-existant (using wget's timeout).

Note that this script assumes that logfile indexing starts with 1, not zero, as you mentioned in example.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. I get a "let: not found" error. and then, since max is undefined I get an error in the line after that.

Comment: Hm, obviously you have some different bash version. :-( OK, I changed script not to use "let", but direct expression in for loop instead. Try now, and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a Perl script that looks like what you want

http://osix.net/modules/article/?id=677

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$program="wget"; #change this to proz if you have it ;-)
my $count=1; #the lesson number starts from 1
my $base_url= "http://www.und.nodak.edu/org/crypto/crypto/lanaki.crypt.class/lessons/lesson";
my $format=".zip"; #the format of the file to download
my $max=24; #the total number of files to download
my $url;

for($count=1;$count<=$max;$count++) {
    if($count<10) {
    $url=$base_url."0".$count.$format; #insert a '0' and form the URL
    }
    else {
    $url=$base_url.$count.$format; #no need to insert a zero
    }
    system("$program $url");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had a look at the wget manpage discussion of 'globbing':

By default, globbing will be turned on if the URL contains a globbing character.  This option may be used to turn globbing on or off permanently.
You may have to quote the URL to protect it from being expanded by your shell.  Globbing makes Wget look for a directory listing, which is system-specific.  **This is why it currently works only with Unix FTP servers** (and the ones emulating Unix "ls" output).

So wget http://... won't work with globbing.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your system has seq, then it would be easy:

```
for i in $(seq -f "%03g" 1 10); do wget "http://.../dbsclog${i}.log"; done
```

If your system has the jot command instead of seq:

```
for i in $(jot -w "http://.../dbsclog%03d.log" 10); do wget $i; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh! this is a similar problem I ran into when learning bash to automate manga downloads.

Something like this should work:

```
for a in `seq 1 999`; do
if [ ${#a} -eq 1 ]; then
    b="00"
elif [ ${#a} -eq 2 ]; then
    b="0"
fi
echo "$a of 231"
wget -q http://site.com/path/fileprefix$b$a.jpg
```

done

Comment: Under some circumstances, you might need a lot of `if` statements (or a case statement). Or you could use something like this: `b=000; for a in 1 10 100 1000; do echo "${b:${#a}-1}$a"; done`

Answer (score -1):

Late to the party, but a real easy solution that requires no coding is to use the DownThemAll Firefox add-on, which has the functionality to retrieve ranges of files.  That was my solution when I needed to download 800 consecutively numbered files.